# Looking for arXiv references on Einstein doubts about reality of gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, coordinate-systems, gravitational-waves, history

I'm looking for good papers on arXiv that tells the story of gravitational waves **theoretical discovery** and Einstein's (and others) **doubts on their physical existence**.

Of course, I searched the papers on arXiv, but only found these two:

- J. L. Cervantes-Cota, S. Galindo-Uribarri and G. F. Smoot, "A Brief History of Gravitational Waves", [*Universe* **2016**, 2(3), 22](https://doi.org/10.3390/universe2030022), [arXiv:1609.09400](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09400).
- C.-M. Chen, J. M. Nester and W.-T. Ni, "A brief history of gravitational wave research", [*Chin. J. Phys.* **55** 1, 142-169 (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cjph.2016.10.014), [arXiv:1610.08803](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08803).

I'm looking for something more specific, **on the doubts that Einstein himself got**, and other skeptics arguments.

Any suggestions on the theoretical discovery of gravitational waves, on arXiv, and the doubts that Einstein and others got on that subject?

Comment: You probably already know this: "Einstein submitted this research to the Physical Review under the title “Do Gravitational Waves Exist?” with Rosen as coauthor. Although the original version of the paper no longer exists..."  https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2117822

Comment: Since you are asking for arxiv stuff, i also found this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04674

Comment: Your second reference, section 5 provides a reference for the “Kennefick’s book [115]  <…> Chapter 5”, as well as summary of its content. Is there anything more that you need? Also, perhaps this would be more suited for [History of Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Kennefick's book(s) are definitely the first go to for this sort of thing.